# how do i get the actual dom of an html page output as a string

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to debug a problem at a remote computer that I am unable to reproduce on my system. Once the page loads, dom objects are added dynamically via javascript calls. I need to get the output of the page as it is rendered by the browser. View source only retrieves the pages original content. I need the content AFTER it has finished being rendered and any DOM changes were made.

To be more specific, when using the developer tools in Chrome, the "elements" tab shows the actual code I am interested in receiving from the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve it using javacsript? Then try this:

```
alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

If with a browser - you should install firebug extension, it shows the DOM as a browser sees it. But the saved actual dom may not work, because all dynamically attached element event handlers would be lost.

Comment: The user has IE7 installed and it is only happening on that browser. As far as I know, IE7 does not have dev tools. Your solution is what I was looking for ... but now I need to figure out a way to store that information where the user can send it back to me....

Comment: @Briedus - Wish I could, but have IE8 installed. Unless you know of a way to have it run them together?

Comment: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2006/04/test-internet-explorer-7-without.html or you can install Virtual Box and set up any OS you want (a XP with it's default IE7 for example).

Comment: Thanks for the idea but not available in this shop  :(