# JavaScript to output DOM to HTML file, automated

Tags: javascript, html, dom, automation

I am creating a simple website that use static html files. Actually, the html files should also work offline from a file directory (a documentation set). However, there are some repeated information in these files that makes the set of files not so DRY (don't repeat yourself).

I would like to automatically create static HTML files from source HTML files with JavaScript code in them. An output HTML file should be the DOM HTML *after* JavaScript code has run in the corresponding input HTML file.

Somehow, it should be possible to accomplish this in an automated fashion, but how? Can Jetty achieve this somehow, maybe? Can a stand-alone JavaScript engine (such as Rhino) "run" HTML files?

Please, do not suggest to run client-side JavaScript or server-side HTML generation, I need plain old static HTML files.

Related questions:

[how do i get the actual dom of an html page output as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064272/how-do-i-get-the-actual-dom-of-an-html-page-output-as-a-string)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622844/can-i-see-the-resulting-markup-after-javascript-dom-manipulation

Comment: What you need is static site generator, search on Google for them.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of them. However, I have not found one that does what I want according to my description above.

Comment: Solution to your problem should make sense only if you have a file called source_template.html lets say, which you can inherit or include in all your static pages somehow... Do u think you can do that ?
Otherwise it might not still be so DRY